# Equivalence between $SP_{h}(X)$ and $\Gamma^{+}(X)$ in simplicial context

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, stable-homotopy-theory

According to the article [*The homotopy infinite symmetric product represents stable homotopy theory*](http://msp.org/agt/2007/7-4/agt-v7-n4-p10-p.pdf), Proposition 4.5 states:

> There is an equivalence of topological monoids $$\pi:SP_{h}(X)\xrightarrow{\thicksim} \mathrm{\Gamma}^{+}(X)$$
>   for any pointed CW-complex $X$.

The autor, Schlichtkrull, asserts **we may work over simplicial sets throughout that paper (actually, he works over topological spaces)**, so I would like to prove this proposition in its simplicial version. At some point of the proof, $X$ is supposed to be the geometric realization of a pointed simplicial set $X_{\bullet}$ as a particular case
[image: homotopy infinite symmetric product]
 then the general case follows from this.  
 Nevertheless, what is the trick when $X\in\mathbf{sSet}_{\ast}$? (I mean what is the analogous step at this point).
Thanks.

Comment: I haven't read the paper, but a weak equivalence of simplicial sets are those maps whose geometric realization is a weak equivalence of spaces.  So it seems that you can cut out the commutative square; all you need is that the bottom map is an equivalence.

Comment: Thanks JHF. Yes, but as far as I know, when $X\in\mathbf{sSet}_{\ast}$ we have $SP_{h}(\lvert X\rvert)\cong \lvert SP_{h}(X)\rvert$ and $\Gamma^{+}(\lvert X\rvert)\cong\lvert \Gamma^{+}(X)\rvert$, so the equivalence follows from Schlichtkrull's result. However I would like to get an 'independent' proof.

Comment: I think there may be a misunderstanding.  I think you want to prove that $SP_h(X_\bullet) \xrightarrow{\sim} \Gamma^+(X_\bullet)$.  But whatever proposition 4.3 is, the wording in the pasted proof seems to indicate that it proves that it's a levelwise equivalence.

Comment: Dear JHF, does the fact that a map between simplicial spaces is a levelwise equivalence imply that it induce an homotopy equivalence on geometric realizations?

Comment: For simplicial spaces, some cofibrancy condition is required.  IIRC, the geometric realization of a levelwise weak equivalence between *proper* simplicial spaces is a weak homotopy equivalence.